# Regarding .pop and .remove on a list

Tags: python

I'm having a very weird problem with my python now and I don't know if it's a bug or not.

When I have a list `l = ["a", "b"]`,

And i assign that list to another variable:

`other = l`,

and then try to `.remove` or `.pop` something from `other`, `l` changes with it.

So if I were to do `other.remove("a")`, both `other` and `l` only contain `["b"]`, As if I was passing the list by reference.

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: This is the standard behavior of Python. `other` is a copy of the reference-to-list that `l` is - you didn't do a deep copy on the list.

Comment: Is it? I never knew that and I've been developing in python for quite some time now. huh

Comment: Assignment is always a reference in Python, never a copy.

Comment: I'd usually just do other = l[:]  instead of getting into deepcopy, but I'm not sure what the advantages of deepcopy are over that.

Comment: @mauve i[:] wont be good if there is a list of lists. The internal list will still be just a reference to the old one :) same if there is a list of dicts or any other iterable.

Comment: @pyjg I KNEW there was a reason there was a function for this. Thanks! That's something I've never specifically needed, and now I know to look out for it.

Comment: haha you are welcome, same issue if there is a class, see here https://repl.it/KPeJ